# How to set solr index data path version 9.2.0

Tags: solr, solr9

I have a linux system and installed solr 9.2.0 and started solr. My solr installation path is /opt/solr-9.2.0/ and I tried creating a core by doing the following steps

```
    mkdir -p /opt/solr-9.2.0/server/solr/samplecore/conf
    cp -pr /opt/solr-9.2.0/server/solr/configsets/sample_techproducts_configs/conf /opt/solr-9.2.0/server/solr/samplecore
```

I created core.properties in the location /opt/solr-9.2.0/server/solr/samplecore/ with below content by referring to a sample version from another very old version installation

```
    #Written by CorePropertiesLocator
    #Wed May 03 17:32:11 PDT 2023
    name=samplecore
    config=solrconfig.xml
    schema=schema.xml
    dataDir=/index/dev/solr/samplecore
```

I started solr as below
`/opt/solr-9.2.0/bin/solr start -h mylinuxbox -p 8983`

After this I visited http://mylinuxbox:8983/solr in browser and expected to see the created core but i 'm getting an error as follows

SolrCore Initialization Failures
samplecore: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/index/dev/solr/samplecore/snapshot_metadata" "read")
Please check logs for more information.

Is there any other setting or configuration I am missing? I need the solr to use /index/dev/solr/samplecore path for index data. Please help me with this. I am new to solr and java.

I have explained in the description everything I tried

Comment: Does the user that Solr runs as _have access to `/index/dev/solr/samplecore`? Does the directory exist? What are the current access rights on the directory? Who owns the directory?

Comment: Yes, the directory structure exists and has 0775 permissions.

Comment: The directory is also owned by user and group that runs solr.

Comment: We're having the same issue with 9.2.1 on RHEL7. I opened the directory up completely and get the same message in the log. It also complains about read access to the parent dir (e.g. `/index/dev/solr/samplecore` for OP).

Answer (score 2):

We noticed that when creating a new core on v9, you cannot point the data directory to a directory that is not within the core's root directory. So in your example, you might need to change your `core.properties` to:

```
    name=samplecore
    config=solrconfig.xml
    schema=schema.xml
    dataDir=data
```

Note that creating a symlink to the data directory (if it's outside of the core's root directory) also causes the same error to occur.

Comment: I tried symlink but that didn’t work and got same error. I got this resolved finally by starting solr without the Java security options. I set it to false in the solr.in.sh file and then restarted solr.

Comment: @TheNerdRaj can you elaborate on which Java security option(s) you had to disable to get this to work?

Comment: In solr.in.sh there is a property SOLR_SECURITY_MANAGER_ENABLED that needs to be set to false instead of true.

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT

The original answer below was required for us due to some quirks of our deployment but might not be necessary for everyone. You may be able to avoid upgrading solr or modifying security.policy and instead just set `SOLR_DATA_HOME` in your solr.in.cmd or solr.in.sh respectively:

`set SOLR_DATA_HOME=C:/path/to/data`
or
`export SOLR_DATA_HOME="/path/to/data"`

Note: We found that using a relative path (`../data`) caused us to still encounter the permission failure.

---

## Original Answer

As of Solr 9.4 there seems to be a proper fix for this issue.

### Short answer

1. Either upgrade to Solr 9.4 or add the following to `solr/server/etc/security.policy`:

   ```
   permission java.io.FilePermission "${solr.allowPaths}", "read,write,delete,readlink";
   permission java.io.FilePermission "${solr.allowPaths}${/}-", "read,write,delete,readlink";
   ```
2. Add the following to your **solr.in.cmd**:

   `set SOLR_OPTS=%SOLR_OPTS% -Dsolr.allowPaths=C:\path1\to\allow,C:\path2\to\allow`

   or **solr.in.sh**:

   `SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dsolr.allowPaths=/path1/to/allow,/path2/to/allow"`
3. Restart solr.

### Long Answer

As noted in previous answers, solr 9 comes with the java security manager enabled by default. This prevents solr from accessing directories outside of its root directory. This is why previous answers suggested disabling the security manager.

In Solr 8.6 a `solr.allowPaths` property was added for specifying allowed paths outside of the default directories. In solr 9.0 -> 9.3 this property was not configured in the security manager. This means that even though you could add your paths to this property, it would still result in a permission error.

This has been resolved in solr 9.4, with the following lines added to the security.policy file in solr/server/etc

```
permission java.io.FilePermission "${solr.allowPaths}", "read,write,delete,readlink";
permission java.io.FilePermission "${solr.allowPaths}${/}-", "read,write,delete,readlink";
```

This means you can now configure the allowPaths property in solr.in.cmd or solr.in.sh as described in step 2 of the short answer above.

If you are unable to upgrade to 9.4 for some reason, you could add these lines to the security.policy manually.

### References:

1. [Security Manager enabled by default (Solr 9 release notes)](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/upgrade-notes/major-changes-in-solr-9.html#security-3)
2. [allowPaths property added (Solr 8.6 update notes)](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_6/solr-upgrade-notes.html#solr-8-6)
3. [Jira ticket describing issue and potential fix to security.policy](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-16905)
4. [Pull Request for fix to security.policy](https://github.com/apache/solr/pull/1811)
5. [security.policy file in 9.4 release tag (lines 216-217)](https://github.com/apache/solr/blob/releases/solr/9.4.0/solr/server/etc/security.policy#L216-L217)

Comment: I didn't use the actual method supplied in this answer but you really helped me understand what was going on which supported me making my own fix (move the mounted data folders inside the `/var/solr` directory. I wish I could vote this up three times ;)

Answer (score 0):

It helps to resolve the dependency for symlink

`SOLR_SECURITY_MANAGER_ENABLED=false`